# Azure AD with MS Graph API, can't grant my app Mail.Read

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

Trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to read Office 365 mail. I can authenticate via Azure AD (not V2) and get a token, but the only permission I get is User.Read. I want Mail.Read.

My app registration in the Azure portal includes a Mail.Read permission: API "Microsoft Graph", permission "Read user mail". In the `/authorize` request, I specify both `resource` and `scope`, the latter being `https://graph.windows.net/mail.read`. Yet when the token JSON comes back, it has `"scope":"User.Read"`. And the request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` returns error 403, while `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/` works as expected.

What am I missing?

EDIT: the initial OAuth URI is:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fredacted.com%2fgoblin%2fback.aspx&client_id=3b595e3f-aecf-4a8c-8ec3-309810d75783&response_mode=query&scope=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.windows.net%2fmail.read&resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.windows.net%2f`

The JSON goes:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "User.Read",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "0",
    "expires_on": "1494364932",
    "not_before": "1494361032",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    "access_token": "redacted",
    "refresh_token": "redacted",
    "id_token": "redacted"
}
```

Comment: Could you add the URI you're using to kick off the OAUTH workflow as well as the actual JSON output being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you simply need to trigger consent again.

If you have an application, and you update the permissions that the application requires, you will need to ask the user to consent to the new permissions you require.

In your code, you should have a logic check that says:

- `if` missing scope, `then` prompt for consent again

You can prompt for consent by adding the following query string directly  to the login url: `&prompt=consent`

Otherwise, you can use the `PromptBehavior` parameter in ADAL.

Comment: With single-tenant apps this is still pretty simple, gets a bit more difficult in multi-tenant :)